# Laravel format time

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with getting time on my app. I'm using laravel api to send informations to my React app.
I have controller like:

```
public function index(){

        $user = auth()->user();
        $servers = Server::where('clientid', $user->id)
               ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();

        if ($user) {
            $reposne['result'] = true;
            $reposne['servers'] = $servers;
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $reposne;
    }
```

And it's successfuly returns what I need, like:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "servers": [
        {
            "id": 2512,
            "clientid": 4,
            "boxid": 23,
            "ipid": 60,
            "vazido": 1584355476,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "status": "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

But as you see there is column `vazido` that is actyally giving a timestamp. How can I make this time to actual human format?

Comment: what is the type of this column in your mysql

Answer (score 0):

> By default, timestamps are formatted as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

I think your column type is **int** or **string**. So you can change the column type to `timestamp` or `datetime`.

```php
$table->datetime('vazido')->change();
```

Or you can use [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to convert the number to the datetime format, add this method to your Server Model:

```php
    public function getVazidoAttribute($value) {
      return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `$casts` attribute in your Server Model and Laravel will handle the rest for you.

**Sever Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Server extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'vazido' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model, You can use [Eloquent Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators) to formate the date as following.

```
public function getVazidoAttribute($value)
{
     return $value->format('Y-m-d');
}
```